# Transeferring data from NCBI database to another site using Javascript and php

Tags: php, javascript, data-binding, bioinformatics

NCBI is a Bioinformatic and biological sequences database. It user interface is english. I am planing a site which show data from this site with non english descriptions. I need to connect NCBI blast data base and make search there and then transfer result to the blast box in my site. How can I do this using JavaScript and php? Is there any better way(s) to do this?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> ". I need to connect NCBI blast data base"

you can fetch the data from the NCBI as XML
using NCBI utilities: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25500/

you could also ask biostars: http://biostars.org